# Replace Multiple Values On Python or EXCEL

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, excel-formula

Seeking for Help. Hi Guys i didnt code yet because i think i need some idea to access the csv and the row. so technically i want to replace the text with the id on the CSV file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('replace.csv')
print(df)
```

Please kindly view the photo. so if you see there is 3 column, so i want to replace the D Column if the D Column is Equal to A Column, then replace with the ID (column B). seeking for i idea if what is the first step or guide.. thanks

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGWIW.png)

In The Photo

```
name  | id | Replace
james | 5  | James,James,Tom
tom   | 2  | Tom,James,James
jerry | 10 | Tom,Tom,Tom
```

What Im Expected Result:

```
name  | id | Replace
james | 5  | 5,5,2
tom   | 2  | 2,5,5
jerry | 10 | 2,2,2
```

Comment: Hi i added sir what i want to do

Comment: Can you help me with excel or google sheet i think that a good i dea? where is the simple way to do it? please help me to acheive that on google sheet or exel

Comment: @JvdV this is the wrong formula im using =VLOOKUP(A3,$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Excel 365:**

As per my comment, if it's ok to get data in a new column *and* with ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=MAP(C2:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),A2:A4,B2:B4,"",0))))
```

Or, if all values will be present anyways:

```
=MAP(C2:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),A2:B4,2,0))))
```

---

**Google-Sheets:**

The Google-Sheets equivalent, as per your request, could be:

```
=MAP(C2:C4,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",",,VLOOKUP(SPLIT(x,","),A2:B4,2,0)))))
```

---

**Python/Pandas:**

After some trial and error I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('replace.csv', sep=';')
df['Replace'] = df['Replace'].replace(pd.Series(dict(zip(df.name, df.id))).astype(str), regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name  id Replace
0  James   5   5,5,2
1    Tom   2   2,5,5
2  Jerry  10   2,2,2
```

**Note:** I used the semi-colon as seperator in the function call to open the CSV.

Comment: Hello thank you im getting error text slip how to fix that?

Comment: it is possible to upload the file? this is for excel right? not google sheet?

Comment: @nidiv, I also included a Pandas solution that seems to work fine too.

Comment: it is possible to avoid #N/A when the "name" is missing?

Comment: For GS: `=MAP(C2:C4,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(x;","),A2:B4,2,0),"Missing")))))` I suppose. For Excel you should use the `XLOOKUP()` variant @nidiv

Comment: im getting invalid function when using this on excel idk why

Comment: WORKS WELL ON GOOGLESHEET!!! THANK YOU AGAIN!!!!

Comment: You may not have the appropriate Excel version. But why not just use the Pandas solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nested =substitute functions would make this easy.

```
=substitute(substitute(substitute(d2, a2, b2),a3,b3),a4,b4)
```